# Reshape specific rows into columns in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

My sample data frame would look like the following:

```
1   Number       Type     Code   Reason
2   0123          06       09     010  
3   Date        Amount    Damage  Act  
4   08/31/16    10,000      Y      N   
5   State        City      Zip   Phone
6   WI            GB       1234    Y
```

I want to make rows 1, 3, and 5 column names and have the data below each fall into each column, respectively. I was looking into the `reshape` function, but I only saw examples where an entire column of values needed to be individual columns. So I wasn't sure what to do in this scenario--apologies if it's obvious.

Here is the desired output:

```
1   Number  Type    Code    Reason  Date        Amount  Damage  Act  State  City  Zip  Phone  
2   0123    06       09      010    08/31/16    10,000    Y      N     WI    GB   1234   Y
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how your desired output should look like?

Comment: Hi @USER_1, I updated my post to show the output.

Comment: You have only 4 rows in your data?

Comment: There are actually 8 rows of data with 5 columns--So I would want to make rows 1,3,5, and 7 columns. I just did 4 rows for simplicity. This will be duplicated 100's of times all from different web pages.

Comment: I think showing 8 rows will be more useful. Also, maybe show `dput(your_data)` instead

Comment: If you data is so small, you can do something along the lines of: `df2 <- cbind(df1[2,], df1[4,]); 
names(df2) <- as.character(unlist(c(df1[1,], df1[3,])))`

Comment: That's the solution I was going for.

Comment: This solution won't work for 8 rows though.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, why would it not work for 8 rows? The concept seemed to work for my data frame.

Comment: Because there are specific row specified here. Unless writing every single row by hand is fine with you. I was thinking in the direction of what 42- posted.

Answer (score 1):

As some people have commented, you could build a data frame out of the rows of your starting data frame, but I think it's a little easier to work on the lines of text.

If your starting file looks something like this

```
Number   ,    Type   ,  Code   ,Reason
0123     ,     06    ,   09    , 010  
Date     ,   Amount  ,  Damage , Act  
08/31/16 ,   10000   ,    Y    ,  N   
State    ,    City   ,   Zip   , Phone
  WI     ,       GB  ,     1234,    Y
```

we can read it in with each line as an element of a character vector:

```
lines <- readLines("start.csv")
```

make all the odd lines into a single line:

```
oddind <- seq(from=1, to= length(lines), by=2)
namelines <- paste(lines[oddind], collapse=",")
```

make all the even lines into a single line:

```
datlines <- paste(lines[oddind+1], collapse=",")
```

make those lines into a new CSV to read:

```
writeLines(text= c(namelines, datlines), con= "nice.csv")
print(read.csv("nice.csv"))
```

This gives

```
  Number Type Code Reason      Date Amount    Damage    Act     State
1    123    6    9     10 08/31/16   10000     Y       N      WI     
         City  Zip Phone
1        GB   1234     Y
```

So, it's all in one row of the data frame and all the variable names show up correctly in the data frame.

The benefits of this strategy are:

- It will work for starting CSV files where the number of variables isn't a multiple of 4.
- It will work for starting CSV files with any number of rows
- There is no chance of weird dynamic casting happening with unlist() or as.character().

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dataframe roughly appearing like that (although it necessarily has column names). Those are probably factor columns if you just used one of the standard `read.*` functions without using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, hence the need to convert with as.character.

```
dat=read.table(text="1   Number       Type     Code   Reason
2   0123          06       09     010  
3   Date        Amount    Damage  Act  
4   08/31/16    10,000      Y      N   
5   State        City      Zip   Phone
6   WI            GB       1234    Y")
```

Then you can set odd number rows as names of the values-vector of the even number rows with:

```
 setNames( unlist( lapply( dat[!c(TRUE,FALSE), ] ,as.character)), 
           unlist( lapply( dat[c(TRUE,FALSE), ] ,as.character)) )

         1          3          5     Number       Date      State       Type 
       "2"        "4"        "6"     "0123" "08/31/16"       "WI"       "06" 
    Amount       City       Code     Damage        Zip     Reason        Act 
  "10,000"       "GB"       "09"        "Y"     "1234"      "010"        "N" 
     Phone 
       "Y"
```

The `!c(TRUE,FALSE)` and its logical complement in the next extract operation get magically recycled along all the possible rows. Obviously there would be better ways of doing this if you posted a version of a text file rather than saying that the starting point was a dataframe. You would need to remove what were probably rownames. If you want a "clean solution then post either `dput(.)` from your dataframe or the raw text file.